# Actionscript Performance drops

Tags: performance, actionscript-3

I'm working on a game and it runs quick for a bit but after leaving it to run for a few minutes it starts eating the CPU. The memory stays constant though and I can't figure out the cause. Could it be from the vector drawing? Thanks for any ideas.

```
package {
import caurina.transitions.Tweener;

import com.freeactionscript.CollisionTest;

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

[SWF(frameRate=60, width=640, height=960, backgroundColor=0x000000)]

public class Eye extends Sprite
{

    public var Overlay:Sprite;
    public var Taylor:ThePlayer;
    public var ThePlayerPoint:Point;
    public var Rolyat:TheEye;
    public var EyeBullet:Bullet;
    public var TheEyePoint:Point;
    public var SearchPoint:Point;
    public var LineOfSight:Sprite;
    public var TheEyeSees:Boolean;
    public var Barriers:Array;
    public var BarrierPointL:Point;
    public var BarrierPointR:Point;
    public var Ground:int;
    public var Blocking:int;
    public var MousePoint:Point;

    public var Blocked:Boolean;

    public var Marker:Sprite;

    public var CT:CollisionTest = new CollisionTest();

    public function Eye()
    {

        /**
         * Marker = new Sprite();
         * Marker.graphics.beginFill(0x0C0C0C);
         * Marker.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 5);
         * Marker.graphics.endFill();
         * addChild(Marker);
         */

        Overlay = new Sprite();
        Overlay.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
        Overlay.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
        Overlay.graphics.endFill();
        Overlay.alpha = 0;
        addChild(Overlay);

        Ground = 0.9 * stage.stageHeight;
        graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x000000);
        graphics.moveTo(0, Ground);
        graphics.lineTo(stage.stageWidth, Ground);

        Taylor = new ThePlayer();
        ThePlayerPoint = new Point();
        ThePlayerPoint.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
        ThePlayerPoint.y = Ground - Taylor.height/2;
        Taylor.x = ThePlayerPoint.x;
        Taylor.y = ThePlayerPoint.y;
        addChild(Taylor);

        Rolyat = new TheEye(40, 40);
        Rolyat.scaleX = 0.15;
        Rolyat.scaleY = 0.15;
        TheEyePoint = new Point();
        TheEyePoint.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
        TheEyePoint.y = 100;
        Rolyat.x = TheEyePoint.x;
        Rolyat.y = TheEyePoint.y;
        addChild(Rolyat);

        EyeBullet = new Bullet();

        SearchPoint = new Point();

        MousePoint = new Point();

        LineOfSight = new Sprite();
        addChild(LineOfSight);

        Barriers = new Array(3);
        for(var i:int = 0; i < Barriers.length; i ++) {
            Barriers[i] = new Barrier();
            if(i > 0) {
                Barriers[i].x = Barriers[i - 1].x - 2 * Barriers[i - 1].width;
            } else {
                Barriers[i].x = -Barriers[i].width;
            }
            Barriers[i].y = RandomRange(Rolyat.y + 20, Ground - 20);
            Barriers[i].Update();
            addChild(Barriers[i]);
        }

        BarrierPointL = new Point();
        BarrierPointR = new Point();

        TheEyeSees = true;

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, Update);
        Overlay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Click);

    }

    public function RandomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number {
        return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    //Checks for intersection of Segment if as_seg is true.
    //Checks for intersection of Line if as_seg is false.
    //Return intersection of Segment AB and Segment EF as a Point
    //Return null if there is no intersection
    //---------------------------------------------------------------
    public function lineIntersectLine(A:Point,B:Point,E:Point,F:Point,as_seg:Boolean=true):Point {
            var ip:Point;
            var a1:Number;
            var a2:Number;
            var b1:Number;
            var b2:Number;
            var c1:Number;
            var c2:Number;
         
            a1= B.y-A.y;
            b1= A.x-B.x;
            c1= B.x*A.y - A.x*B.y;
            a2= F.y-E.y;
            b2= E.x-F.x;
            c2= F.x*E.y - E.x*F.y;
         
            var denom:Number=a1*b2 - a2*b1;
            if (denom == 0) {
                    return null;
            }
            ip=new Point();
            ip.x=(b1*c2 - b2*c1)/denom;
            ip.y=(a2*c1 - a1*c2)/denom;
         
            //---------------------------------------------------
            //Do checks to see if intersection to endpoints
            //distance is longer than actual Segments.
            //Return null if it is with any.
            //---------------------------------------------------
            if(as_seg){
                    if(Math.pow(ip.x - B.x, 2) + Math.pow(ip.y - B.y, 2) > Math.pow(A.x - B.x, 2) + Math.pow(A.y - B.y, 2))
                    {
                           return null;
                    }
                    if(Math.pow(ip.x - A.x, 2) + Math.pow(ip.y - A.y, 2) > Math.pow(A.x - B.x, 2) + Math.pow(A.y - B.y, 2))
                    {
                           return null;
                    }
             
                    if(Math.pow(ip.x - F.x, 2) + Math.pow(ip.y - F.y, 2) > Math.pow(E.x - F.x, 2) + Math.pow(E.y - F.y, 2))
                    {
                           return null;
                    }
                    if(Math.pow(ip.x - E.x, 2) + Math.pow(ip.y - E.y, 2) > Math.pow(E.x - F.x, 2) + Math.pow(E.y - F.y, 2))
                    {
                           return null;
                    }
            }
            return ip;
    }

    public function Click(m:MouseEvent):void {
        MousePoint.x = m.localX;
        MousePoint.y = m.localY;
        Tweener.addTween(ThePlayerPoint, {x:m.localX, time:Point.distance(MousePoint, ThePlayerPoint)/stage.stageWidth, transition:"linear"});
    }

    public function UpdateThePlayer():void {
        Taylor.x = ThePlayerPoint.x;
        Taylor.y = ThePlayerPoint.y;
    }

    public function UpdateTheEye():void {
        if(TheEyeSees) {
            Rolyat.ScleraSprite.rotation = Rolyat.ScleraSprite.rotation = (180/Math.PI) * Math.atan(((stage.stageWidth/2) - Taylor.x)/(ThePlayerPoint.y - TheEyePoint.y));
            TheEyeAttack();
        } else {
            if(Rolyat.TurnedRight == false) {
                if(Rolyat.ScleraSprite.rotation <= 30) {
                    Rolyat.ScleraSprite.rotation += 0.8;
                    Rolyat.ScleraSprite.rotation += 0.8;
                }
                if(Rolyat.ScleraSprite.rotation > 30) {
                    Rolyat.TurnedRight = true;
                }
            } else {
                if(Rolyat.ScleraSprite.rotation >= -30) {
                    Rolyat.ScleraSprite.rotation -= 0.8;
                    Rolyat.ScleraSprite.rotation -= 0.8;
                }
                if(Rolyat.ScleraSprite.rotation < -30) {
                    Rolyat.TurnedRight = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function TheEyeAttack():void {
        if(EyeBullet.Ready) {
            EyeBullet.Ready = false;
            EyeBullet.x = Rolyat.x;
            EyeBullet.y = Rolyat.y;
            addChild(EyeBullet);
            Tweener.addTween(EyeBullet, {x:Taylor.x, y:Taylor.y, time:1, transition: "linear", onComplete:BulletExplode});
        }
    }

    public function BulletExplode():void {
        Tweener.addTween(EyeBullet, {scaleX:30, scaleY:30, time:0.25, transition:"linear", onComplete:RemoveBullet});
    }

    public function RemoveBullet():void {
        Tweener.removeTweens(EyeBullet);
        EyeBullet.scaleX = 1;
        EyeBullet.scaleY = 1;
        EyeBullet.Reset();
        removeChild(EyeBullet);
    }

    //Draw LineOfSight to SearchPoint
    public function UpdateLineOfSight():void {
        LineOfSight.visible = false;
        LineOfSight.graphics.clear();
        if(TheEyeSees) {
            LineOfSight.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFFFF00);
        } else {
            LineOfSight.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x66CCCC);
        }
        SearchPoint.x = Math.tan(Math.PI/180 * (-Rolyat.ScleraSprite.rotation)) * (Ground - Rolyat.y) + stage.stageWidth/2;
        SearchPoint.y = Ground;
        LineOfSight.graphics.moveTo(Rolyat.x, Rolyat.y);
        LineOfSight.graphics.lineTo(SearchPoint.x, SearchPoint.y);
    }

    //Check barrier collisions
    public function CheckBarriers():void {
        for(var j:int = 0; j < Barriers.length; j ++) {
            BarrierPointL.x = Barriers[j].x;
            BarrierPointL.y = Barriers[j].y;
            BarrierPointR.x = Barriers[j].x + Barriers[j].width;
            BarrierPointR.y = Barriers[j].y;
            if(Barriers[j].Blocking == false && lineIntersectLine(TheEyePoint, ThePlayerPoint, BarrierPointL, BarrierPointR)) {
                Barriers[j].Blocking = true;
                Blocking ++;
            } else if(Barriers[j].Blocking == true && !(lineIntersectLine(TheEyePoint, ThePlayerPoint, BarrierPointL, BarrierPointR))) {
                Barriers[j].Blocking = false;
                Blocking --;
            }
        }
        if(Blocking == 0 && Math.abs(SearchPoint.x - Taylor.x) <= 50) {
            TheEyeSees = true;
        } else {
            TheEyeSees = false;
        }
    }

    //Move barriers and check collision
    public function UpdateBarriers():void {
        for(var j:int = 0; j < Barriers.length; j ++) {
            Barriers[j].Update();
            if(Barriers[j].x < stage.stageWidth + Barriers[j].width/2) {
                Barriers[j].x += Barriers[j].Speed;
            } else {
                if(j == 0) {
                    Barriers[j].x = Barriers[Barriers.length - 1].x - 5 * Barriers[Barriers.length - 1].width;
                } else {
                    Barriers[j].x = Barriers[j - 1].x - 5 * Barriers[j - 1].width;
                }
                Barriers[j].y = RandomRange(Rolyat.y + 20, Ground - 20);
            }
            CheckBarriers();
        }
    }

    public function Update(e:Event):void {
        setChildIndex(Overlay, numChildren - 1);
        UpdateThePlayer();
        UpdateTheEye();
        UpdateLineOfSight();
        UpdateBarriers();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Nothing stands out as an obvious problem. Maybe you could open your swf in Adobe Scout and get more details as to what is happening. http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/

Comment: Check if the Tweener library correctly drops old tweens. Most likely there's a tween buildup within the library, which eats up CPU to process useless calculations.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Ill check on those. However, in the classes I didn't include I used the graphics class for every object and commenting it out dropped the CPU usage to 3%. I hope it will stay close to that if I just use bitmaps instead.